# download service, controlling file access

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where people buy access to downloads through the woocommerce plugin.

There are usually several thousand downloads for each order and I have found woocommerce to be inefficient when handling large amounts of downloads.

The download files are like this

```
product1_date.pdf

product2_date.pdf

etc...
```

I can't change this

I need a PHP solution which

1. Admin can upload files to a directory via FTP
2. Users who buy a product can download them in their download area
3. Users cannot access files for products they haven't purchased by guessing the filename

1 and 2 I can handle, but how do I prevent 3? Is there a way I can set file permissions to only be read by a specific user who has purchased? Or would is it possible to make the directory writable by everyone (so they can be uploaded) but the files only readable by apache and serve the files to the user some other way?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must stop hotlinks!
After, you create a downloader file contain of downloader function. This's parameters is file mime-type, file name, file url etc... Users can only download with this downloader file. Function is first control users access, after accept user want or not accept. RETURN